# How to optimize the performance of this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that takes about 5 minutes to complete. Is there any way to improve it? My database contains about 300 000 records in each of the tables.

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client_Master B
INNER JOIN Client_Bank C ON B.client_id=C.Client_Id
LEFT JOIN CL_Client_Bank_Details_Dropout A ON A.client_id=B.Client_Id
 WHERE B.Status = 'D'
 AND A.Client_Id IS NULL
```

Comment: where does it takes 5-6 min ? in SSMS or in your software ? And can you include an execution plan from SSMS please

Comment: In SSMS @GuidoG

Comment: OK than you can include the execution plan in your question, without it we can only guess what is going on

Comment: In addition to query plan you also need to include the table structure and indexes + how many rows are there for `Status = 'D'` and for `Client_Id is NULL`

Comment: `statistics io` output is also sometimes useful, so you could include that too.

Comment: Do you really need all the columns in the output? The columns from `CL_Client_Bank_Details_Dropout` will all have the same value `NULL`.